# Split a string into substring using single quote as a split point but not quotes preceded by backslash(\) and followed by another quote

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

Considering this string below, I want to split a string  on a single quote not preceded by \ and not followed by another single quotes('') with regex.

Note: In a string below, those are two consecutive single quotes not double quote.

```
Java is my 'favorite\''\'' prog' language
```

I used

```
split("(?<!\\\\)'")
```

but does not work. Instead it also takes one quote in every consecutive single quotes preceded by back slash

I want this output

```
Java is my  
favorite\''\'' prog  
language
```

Comment: look for regex lookahead/lookbehind

Comment: the rule for what should happen with consecutive quote marks is unclear. For example: `how to ''' split this?`

Comment: Perhaps [`(?<![\\'])' ?(?!['])`](https://regex101.com/r/pRl9bg/1) to take [the whitespace into account](http://rextester.com/OZFLN68056)

Comment: Just make sure you double the backslashes in the string literal when testing in Java.

Comment: Try `s.split("(?<!\\\\')'(?!')")`, but note that it will not work if the backslash itself can be escaped in these strings.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at lookbehind / lookahead

```
("(?<![\\\\'])'(?!')")
```

Comment: If you add `\\'` to your character set, it'll be correct.

Comment: @eli Was going to publish exactly that answer, but better edit this one

Comment: I was going to edit the answer, but refrained from it, as I'd rather leave it up for Graciano to do.

Answer (score 2):

For this example you also might match a single `'` quote and a word boundary `\b` and the other way around:

[`'\b|\b'`](https://regex101.com/r/YW6DnI/2)

```
split("'\\b|\\b' ")
```

[Example Java](http://rextester.com/IVV51826)

Or with a negative lookbehind and negative lookahead taking the whitespace into account:

[`(?<![\\'])' ?(?!')`](https://regex101.com/r/VDo1Xe/2)

```
split("(?<![\\\\'])' ?(?!')")
```

[Example Java](http://rextester.com/NPHY76960)

Credits to [@Graciano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4796797/graciano) for the setup of the solution.

Comment: `'\b|\b'` wouldn't work on `some 'string \' to.' match`. And if you ask me, you should probably give some credit to Graciano for your 2nd solution...

Comment: @eli I see your point, I upvoted Graciano's answer. `'\b|\b'` is only meant for the current example.

Answer (score 0):

From your example I suggest using something similar to

```
split("[^\\\\']'")
```

but be careful with corner cases.